# watchdog does not reset my board

Tags: linux, watchdog

I have a `watchdog` on my system and a driver that uses `/dev/watchdog`.
But the watchdog is not able to recover a crashed system. I crash the system with a kernel panic. Something like below

```
sync; sleep 2; sync; echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

but after the kernel panic my board is not getting rebooted.

*what could be the problem?*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a hw watchdog. Typically it would be armed/enabled during boot time and then one or more processes would have to periodically 'feed' it, otherwise it hw-resets the system.

If so, it sounds like it's not actually active/working. You can check by killing/stopping the feeder process, no need to crash the system.

Orthogonally - I used to add a **kernel.panic = 20** into the **/etc/sysctl.conf** file for my systems to automatically reboot after kernel crashes.